# Get previous and next object in sequence in Django - what is most efficient?

Tags: django, django-models

I have a `Chart` model that consist of multiple `Box` models (so `Box` has a foreign key to `Chart`). The `Box` models have a field `number` that defines their order inside the `Chart`.

Now `Box` will have a method that returns it's contents. What the contents is, depends on the properties of the previous box and the next one (if there are any). So from the `Box` model I need to have a reference to the preceding `Box` and the upcomming `Box`.

Now I see two options:

- Make foreign keys for the previous and next `Box`.
- Ask `Chart` for a box where `number = (current box number -1 or +1)`

What would be the most efficitent way to do this and why? If I use the foreignkey method, will it do extra queries or does it make this connections automatically? Of course I must use `select_related` on the queryset to get the complete `Chart`. And what option do you think is most scalable?

I know I can test this of course but I wonder what other people might think of this and if there are other solutions to this that I didn't realize.

Comment: Why do you have multiple `Box` models and what do they do?

Comment: What does this mean "what the content is, depends on the contents of the previous box" - a box's contents won't change.

Comment: @Burhan Khalid sorry, changed it to "what the contents is, depends on the properties of the previous and the next box".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible solution is the following method in the `Box` model:

```
def get_ordering(self):
   try:
       top = Box.models.filter(number__lt=self.number).order_by('-number')[0]
   except IndexError:
       top = None

   try:
       bottom = Box.models.filter(number__gt=self.number).order_by('number')[0]
   except IndexError:
       top = None

   return top,bottom
```

However, a better solution would be to use [`django-mptt`](https://github.com/django-mptt/django-mptt) an implementation of tree traversal for django.

Comment: Thanks. It's pretty similar to my first option. Do you think this is better than having foreign keys?

Comment: `django-mptt` seems like a promising solution, I'll take a look into it! Thanks

Comment: `django-mptt` seems to use the same technique you proposed (https://github.com/django-mptt/django-mptt/blob/master/mptt/models.py#L534) so maybe it's better to do it myself than having a big library behind it.

Comment: Excellent answer and very pythonic Khalid. Good that you use `try` and `except` because with `if` and `else` it is easier to get stuck.